# Code generation for short-circuit Boolean operators

Tags: compiler-construction, code-generation, boolean-expression

What would be an example of a `boolean expression` in which the outcome would be different if short-circuit
evaluation is used than if the boolean expressions are fully evaluated. Then I was wonder how would I sketch it out in terms of the three address
intermediate code for the short-circuit evaluation of your boolean expression?

Comment: Your actual question doesn't have anything to do with semantic analysis or type checking.

Answer (score 4):

The most common use of short-circuiting booleans is to ensure that undefined computations are not performed. In other words, it is not so much that the value of the expression differs with short-circuiting as that the value of the expression is well-defined.

For example, consider a common C idiom:

```
if ( ptr != NULL && *ptr == some_value ) { /* Do something */ }
```

In this case, the short-circuiting `&&` ensures that the pointer will not be dereferenced if it happens to be `NULL`. With full evaluation, the computation would presumably do something really undesirable (like segfault) if the first condition were false.

Since the point of the short-circuiting evaluation is to conditionally not evaluate a part of the expression, the TAC implementation needs to include a conditional branch statement after the evaluation of the left-hand expression. In other words, the above statement would be compiled in a very similar manner to the equivalent:

```
if ( ptr != NULL ) {
  if ( *ptr == some_value ) {
    /* Do something */
  }
}
```

which would presumably be implemented with two conditional jumps.

I'm not sure what this has to do with semantic analysis or type checking.